# Ldap configuration for FR3LdapBundle

Tags: symfony, ldap, fr3dldapbundle

I configured FR3DLdapBundle.

I have to modify app/config/config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
fr3d_ldap:
 client:
    host:         192.168.1.101
    username:     cn=admin,dc=test,dc=local
    password:     12345
    optReferrals: false

    baseDn: dc=test, dc=local
    filter: (&(ObjectClass=*))
    attributes:
       - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setUserName }
```

But it is not working.
Adding the phpldapadmin screenshot.

[image]

Is the configuration right?
what is the " user_method: setUserName" ?

Comment: Please better explain your problem, and write something more specific than just "it is not working".

Comment: Created a login page and tried to authenticate using LDAP. That is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attributes:
       - { ldap_attr: mail,  user_method: setUserName }
```

Means LDAP Attribute "mail" will be passed as argument to the method "setUserName" of your User class

attribute mail seems to don't exists accord your screenshot.

Did you modified the security.yml too?